# How to call a child which belongs to different activity group?

Tags: android, android-activity

From an activity group how to call a child which belongs to different activity group ?

My DealDetailsActivity.java  is a child activity of an  ActivityGroup named TabGroupactivity. In this, I am calling another activity named ViewStoreActivity like this.

```
Intent frequentMessages = new Intent(getParent(),ViewStoreActivity.class);
 TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
 parentActivity.startChildActivity("ViewStoreActivity", frequentMessages);
```

And its working.
From another activity named RedeemedActivity, which is a child of another ActivityGroup named FavouriteGroupActivity, I m calling DealDetailsActivity like this;
 Intent frequentMessages = new Intent(getParent(),DealDetailsActivity.class);
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("DealDetailsActivity_fav", frequentMessages);

After that when I tried to call ViewStoreActivity like the first code, I m getting error.

```
01-23 10:44:04.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1807): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dom.shoppers.FavouriteGroupActivity cannot be cast to com.dom.shoppers.TabGroupActivity
```

the super class of viewstoreactivity is TabGroupActivity.

and the classcastexception is occurring here 
ie 
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();

Thai is ,standing in an activity which belongs to a different activitygroup named TabGroupActivityFavs i am trying to call an activity which belongs to Tabgroupactivity.
so the error is occuring saying that TabGroupActivityFavs cannot be cast to TabGroupActivity.

is there any way to implement this....

if i am using startactivity(), then i am not viewing the tabs. since i wants the tabs consistent for all activities ,i cant use that....

any idea ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying. What is the direct super class of `ViewStoreActivity`? I assume from the LogCat entry that you posted that it is FavouriteGroupActivity. Is that correct? And also, what line is the error being thrown on?

Is it `Intent frequentMessages = new Intent(getParent(), DealDetailsActivity.class);`?

Or `parentActivity.startChildActivity("DealDetailsActivity_fav", frequentMessages`? I'm pretty sure that it should be this line that is throwing the error, but please tell me if I'm wrong. The reason you're getting the error is because ViewStoreActivity is not a child of TabGroupActivity. When you call startChildActivity you're basically telling it to start a child activity that doesn't belong to TabGroupActivity.

Would it be possible for you to call startActivity() instead of startChildActivity()? If you call startActivity() then it should take care of your error.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Please let me know if that works for you.